# Set react state from sqlite

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sqlite

I am new to react. Trying to set state from sqlite if data exists or fetch data from api if not. Now the result from sqlite select is showing correct, however setting state fails with error message:

**WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection**

It seems like state is undefined. It works to set state in the fetch code. Why is state undefined in the database transaction?

```
class ClassyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            DataisLoaded: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("state1:" + this.state.data),
      db.transaction(function (txn) {
        txn.executeSql("select * from dinners", 
        [],
        (trans, result) => {
          console.log("result: " + result.rows._array[0].data),
          this.setState({
            data: result.rows._array[0].data
          });
        });
      })
        
      fetch(
        "https://somefancyurl"
          )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            console.log("state:" + this.state.data)
              this.setState({
                  data: json,
                  DataisLoaded: true
              });
          }
      )
  }
}
```